# Configuring portable browser binary via Robot framework

Tags: selenium, webdriver, automated-tests, robotframework, portable-executable

I need to run my Robot test scripts using portable browsers of specific versions, instead of the one those are installed on the host machine. How can I achieve this? Is there any option available in Selenium Capabilities?

My requirement is for Chrome, IE, and Firefox - all these browser's portable versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method to specify the binary file location as an experimental option before calling `Create Webdriver` keyword.

```
Call Method ${chromeOptions}    add_experimental_option prefs   ${prefs}
${chromeOptions.binary_location}    Set Variable    <insert your path here>     
Create Webdriver    Chrome  chrome_options=${chromeOptions}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done this way (same answer as @GPT14, but more complete):

```
${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
${prefs}       Create Dictionary
Call Method    ${options}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
${options.binary_location}    Set Variable    ${setYourPathToChromePortableHere}
Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${options}
Go To    ${URL}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to manipulate the PATH environment variable so that it finds the portable browser first that the installed one (and before calling `Create Webdriver` or `Open Browser`).

This can be done using OperatingSystem keywords, like for example, `Set Environment Variable`.